# arc4random initialisation

Tags: objective-c, arc4random

I am using random number generation as part of a procedure for minimising a function (using the ***Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm***) in objective-c (for iOS).  I have used `arc4random()` because it seems to be recommended everywhere on the grounds that a) it doesn't need to be seeded and b) it gives higher-quality random numbers than alternatives such as `rand() and random()`. I generate doubles between 0 and 1 using

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x100000000
-(double) Rnd{
return (double)arc4random() / (double)ARC4RANDOM_MAX ; }
```

However, to test the procedure I need to generate repeatable sequences of random numbers, and I can't find any reference to a way to initialise `arc4random()` to do this.  Is it the case that `arc4random()` cannot be initialised to give a repeatable sequence?  If so, how can anyone implement an automated unit test when every test will result in a different answer? Do I need to use the "lower quality" random numbers from `random()`?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `arc4random` function gets random numbers from a pool over which it has no control. It has no mechanism to provide repeatability. For unit tests, you'll have to use something else.

Comment: Thanks for this, David.  I suspected as much, but wanted confirmation.